# Wordpress change URL parameter on custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with a plugin in the backend which sets a `$_GET` parameter to my pages URL. Now I need to replace the value from this parameter with my custom value but this won't work:

> My URL:
>   http://localhost/wordpress/mein-konto/testpage/585/?conversationId=0

On the testpage/585 I've included a PHP file which get loaded on page load. In this file I have this function:

```
add_query_arg( 'conversationId', 1234, get_permalink() );
```

Now I'm expecting this URL here:

> http://localhost/wordpress/mein-konto/testpage/585/?conversationId=1234

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are you using this ? what's the use case ? `add_query_args()` **returns** a modified url string

Comment: @msg I'm using this on my php file. This is the only parameter I set so I'm expecting that the URL changes with the one row of code

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some code ? The function returns a string. Without seeing more code invoking this, it makes no sense to me. Are you redirecting to that url? Are you outputting it as a link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$conversationId = get_query_var( 'conversationId', '0' )

if ($conversationId === '0')
    wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'conversationId', 1234, get_permalink() ) )
```

It sounds like you are expecting `add_query_arg` to do the redirection, but it does not -- instead, it just returns a string that you can redirect to. So, just put the returned string into a call to `wp_safe_redirect` and you are good!

However, before redirecting to the same page you need to check whether the redirection is necessary -- otherwise you'll end up in an endless redirection loop (that your browser will detect and stop).